# Have text continue "behind" a minipage that's on its own page

Tags: minipage

What I'm after is a way to get the following:

- Page n: text...reference to content of minipage...text to end of page
- Page n+1: minipage only
- Page n+2: text continues from end of page n

without having to manually position and reposition the minipage within the .tex document. That is, the order of the relevant content of the .tex document should be:

1. (text)
2. (reference to content of minipage)
3. (minipage content)
4. (text to end of page)
5. (text continues etc.)

Is there a way to do this, perhaps with something other than minipage?

Edit: Here is code that does *not* work:

```
This text is on page n. There will be a minipage on the next page.

\newpage
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
This is my minipage on its own page.
\end{minipage}
\newpage

This text is on the wrong page. 
It should follow the sentence ``There will be a minipage on the next page."
```

Comment: Welcome :) // Yes, it can be done. The rule of the game here is: you provide code with your own trials, demonstrating where you succeed and fail, and we help you along. So, please provide your code. Thanks.

Comment: Actually in this case a MWE would serve more as something we can copy-paste tweak a little bit to prettify it. Post a working document that you do the "positioning" manually, and explain what part you want to make automatic.

Comment: Sounds like you're just describing the normal behavior of a float environment though.

Comment: Have a look at tcolorbox, manual sec. 4.13, floating objects.

Comment: Put `\newpage` before and after the minipage? Or define a custom environment: `\newenvironment{xyz}{\newpage\begin{minipage}{3in}}{\end{minipage}\newpage}`?

Comment: @MS-SPO. Thank you. I've added code now.

Comment: @Cicada That's not what I want. See the code above and the description in the post.

Comment: @user202729 As I understand it, using a float environment won't ensure that the content in the environment ends up by itself on the very next page, which is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses the afterpage package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\afterpage{\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
  \centering\fbox{Minipage contents}
\end{minipage}}

\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to work! Thank you. It seems one can also follow the first \afterpage{...} with \afterpage{\clearpage} to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you add, inside the John Kormylo answer, `\thispagestyle{empty}` you can mark a empty page without heater or footer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\afterpage{\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
  \thispagestyle{empty}\centering\fbox{Empty page}
\end{minipage}}

\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

[image]